# A binomial identity question.

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I need to calculate

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k}{m_1}\binom{m_2}{k}(-1)^k$$

where $1\leq m_2 \leq m_1 \leq n$. Any help or tips on how to proceed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably want $m_1\leq m_2,$ because the sum is zero when $m_1>m_2.$

Comment: Note that
$$(1-(1+x))^{m_2}=\sum_{k=0}^{m_2}\binom{m_2}{k}(-1)^k(1+x)^k$$
$$=\sum_{m_1=0}^{m_2}\sum_{k=0}^{m_1}\binom{k}{m_1}\binom{m_2}{k}(-1)^kx^{m_1}$$

Comment: Please do not edit to change the question after you get an answer. If you have a new question, please make a new post.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\binom{m_2}{k}\binom{k}{m_1}=\binom{m_2}{m_1}\binom{m_2-m_1}{k-m_1}$$